# Argparse: Passing multiple arguments via optional parameters when there is also a positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

When I have an `argparse` interface that only supports optional parameters, e.g.

```
parser.add_argument('-p', '--ports', nargs='+' type=int)
```

I can pass values to this parameter as follows

```
$ python3 myFunc.py -p 80
```

or even

```
$ python3 myFunc.py -p 80 8080
```

Now, when I add a positional argument at the end of the interface, it is a different story:

```
parser.add_argument('-p', '--ports', nargs='+' type=int)
parser.add_argument('host', nargs=1)
```

When I try to call the script like before, with the positional argument at the end, I am getting the following error:

```
$ python3 myFunc.py -p 80 10.0.0.0.1
usage: myFunc.py [-h] [-p ports [ports ...]] host
myFunc.py: error: argument -p/--ports: invalid int value: '10.0.0.0.1'
```

So it seems that argparse cannot recognize that the last value relates to the positional argument `host` and is not part of `ports`. This can be fixed by using `=` to specify the port. Which I do not find aesthetic, to be honest.

```
$ python3 myFunc.py -p=80 10.0.0.0.1
```

However, while I was able to pass multiple values to `port` in the previous version without `host` by simply add arguments:

```
$ python3 myFunc.py -p=80 8080 443
```

this does not work anymore with the version that supports `host` most likely due to the syntax on how to pass multiple arguments when using the `=` along the optional argument, e.g.

```
$ python3 myFunc.py -p=80,443 10.0.0.0.1
usage: myFunc.py [-h] [-p ports [ports ...]] host
myFunc.py: error: argument -p/--ports: invalid int value: '80,443'
```

In this case, do I need to implement a custom parser for this flag that accepts a string of comma-separated values and split it up internally, or is there any built-in functionality for this?

Comment: The user can use `--` to indicate the end of of optional arguments — `python3 myFunc.py -p 17 42 4711 -- 10.0.0.1`.

Comment: Or put the positional first `myfun 10.0.0.1 -p 80 81 82`

Comment: @hpaulj Yikes! I’m too used to traditional getopt() parsers in C, that stop recognizing options on seeing the first non-option... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `argparse` sees your '-p', it follows the `nargs='+'`, and allocates all the remaining strings to it (or up to next flag string).  '-p' Action then passes those strings to its `type`, `int`, and raises an error when it can't convert the last.

The top down parsing of `argparse`, allocates strings based on flags and `nargs`.  The `type` checking is done after allocation.  Also it does not implement the kind of look-ahead logic required to recognize that there's still a `positional` that needs a string, and thus reserve something for it.

So in general when using `nargs` like '+' and '*', you have to keep in mind that they are 'greedy' and try use grab as much as they can.  So such an argument has to be last, or be followed by another `optional`.

Putting the positional's argument first is one way around this.  The '--' also serves as a "end of list" marker.  Or instead of using a `positional`, define another `optional`.